# Set Xaml Webview

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

In my Windows Store App, I have set a webview in my xaml page :

```
<WebView x:Name="wv1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
<Image x:Name="img" Source="Assets/fb1.png" Stretch="Fill"  Tapped="img_Tapped" />
```

I want that when the Image is tapped on the screen, the webview loads up to the specified uri.

I set the tapped function on the image to navigate to google.com when tapped.

```
  private void wv1_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/");
            wv1.Navigate(uri);

        }
```

But when I tap the image, nothing happens.

How do I fix this so that when I tap the Image on the screen, it uses the webview to navigate to the Google without leaving the App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `WebView` is hardcoded to be `Collapsed`, which is why you aren't seeing it. You'll need to set the `Visibility` of it to `Visible`.

```
wv1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

after you navigate to the URI.

Though, it is recommended to have the `Visibility` of your `WebView` bound to a `Visibility` property so that you can just change the property's value instead of explicitly setting the Visibility yourself.